# Creating a table with a field (with a foreign key) which can reference many tables and maintain referencial integrity?

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

what is the best way of creating a table which can hold a key to a lot of other tables?
As far as I know I have two options:
1) I create a table with a lot of foreign key fields
2) I create two fields, one which indicates the referenced table and another field which holds the primary key of that table.

The latter has a lot of issues due to the fact there's no way to maintain referential integrity (because there's no foreign key to each table).

Besides a link to this table I want to add a description so I can show all notifications in a grid. By clicking a line in the grid I want to open the corresponding program and fix the issue in that program.

It's a bit hard to explain, perhaps this example explains better:
I need to create a system which handles task/notes/notifications for every program in our business application. We have invoices, sales-orders, deliveries, production-orders, etc 
Our software detects that something is wrong which any of these. For instance, if the profits on a sales-order are not high enough the order can't be validated automatically. In this case I want to create a notification for the sales-manager so that he can check out what's wrong with the sales-order.

FYI: Iam using Sybase SQL Anywhere 12.

Does it make any sense?

Comment: There is an option to set ref integrity for #2, do you want it? It works but isn't looking nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved in reverse way. Lets say that you have table `Alerts` where you are going to put all kind of alerts about bad things happened elsewhere. You may reference this table from ALL other tables in your system and create non-mandatory relationship from them. In short it may look like (i'm using MSSQL syntax):

```
create table Alerts(
   ID int not null identity,
   SomeInfoAboutTheProblem varchar(255),
   constraint PK_Alerts primary key (ID)
)

create table Invoices(
   ID....
   AlertID int NULL,
  ....
   constraint FK_Invoices2Alerts foreign key (AlertID) references Alerts(ID)
)
```

In case you cannot modify your tables with business information you may create "extention" table for `Alerts` that may store some specific problem information and actual reference to the problematic record. For example:

```
create table Alerts(
   ID int not null identity,
   SomeInfoAboutTheProblem varchar(255),
   constraint PK_Alerts primary key (ID)
)
create table Alerts_for_Invoices(
   AlertID int NOT NULL,
   InvoiceID int NOT NULL,
   SomeAdditionalInvoiceProblemInfo ....,
   constraint FK_Alerts_for_Invoices2Alerts foreign key (AlertID) references(ID),
   constraint FK_Alerts_for_Invoices2Invoices foreign key (InvoiceID) references Invoices(ID)
)
```

To show list of problems you may just select general information from Alerts table while opening the dialog you may select all appropriate information regading the problem.